# How to collapse the code section in Google Colab Notebook but keeping the results shown?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

As you can read on the title, I'm currently trying to make the code section collapsing without collapsing also the results section. For example without the collapse the title/code/result sections look like this:

[image: Uncollapsed Section in Google Colab Notebook]

If I try to "collapse" the section will look like this:

[image: Collapsesed Section in Google Colab Notebook]

I'm looking for a solution where I can make collapse the code but not the results sections

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start the cell with

```
#@title
```

Then, you can double click the title. It will hide the code part, but keep the output still visible.

For example

```py
#@title My title
greet = "Hello"
print(greet)
```

Double clicking "My title" will still show the output "Hello".

Comment: Thanks work as intended, didn't collaps as the others section but dobule click on the title and voilà